# Index annotation on a Matlab Plot

Tags: matlab, graph, annotations, plot, figures

I'm facing the following issue:

I'm analyzing the relationship between a certain impedance value (Complex) and Temperature.
The impedance is calculated for a range of Temperature values and then I plot the real and imaginary part of the impedance with plot(Z). My problem is that with this kind of plotting I have no clue on the behavior of the impedance with respect to the temperature.
What I would like to do is to annotate on the graph some temperature points, maybe 4, so that I can know if the curve is growing with the temperature or decreasing with it. I know I can see it by analyzing the absolute value, but I need a more detailed analysis.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something but can you not plot the real and imaginary parts of the impedance as a function of temperature? Something like:

```
plot(temp,real(Z),temp,imag(Z))
legend('Real part','Imaginary part')
xlabel('Temperature')
ylabel('Impedance')
```